# Sequentially pressing each element of a certain class within an SVG

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've been looking for a good example of click events on every element of a certain class, but I can't seem to find one. In my app, I generate multiple bars in an svg with class `.bar`.

Is there a nice way to iterate through each bar in the selection and click it?

Here is my code so far (with the link to dev area removed):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    //open browser, use headless to allowing viewing
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, sloMo: 80});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //goto link
    await page.goto('/link_to_test/');

    //scraping automation goes here
    await page.waitFor(5000);

    let bars = await page.$$(".bar");
    for(const idx in bars){
        await bars[idx].click({delay:250});
    }

    // close browser
    await browser.close();
})();
```

I've been looking for a way to select each bar from the `$$(".bar")` selection and click it but I cannot seem to find any documentation around it.

**Update**

I increased the `page.waitFor` to 5000 and removed the `ElementHandle` from the for loop. Code no longer throws any errors but it doesn't want to click anything.

Looks like this doesn't work for SVG elements yet https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1769

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code I am not sure whether this is the answer you need. This code selects all `a.bars` for a given `ul` and returns an array of all the `hrefs`. We then loop through the links and open each one in turn.

I think the missing bit of the jigsaw is that I am mapping the links to an array (see below  `... links =>  links.map((a) => { return a.href }));`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const html = `
    <html>
      <body>
       <ul>
        <li><a class="bar" href="https://www.google.com">Goolge</a></li>
        <li><a class="bar" href="https://www.bing.com">Bing</a></li>
        <li><a class="bar" href="https://duckduckgo.com">DuckDuckGo</a></li>
       </ul>
      </body>
    </html>`;

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless:false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`);

  const data = await page.$$eval('ul li a.bar', links => 
      links.map((a) => { return a.href }));

  //You will now have an array of hrefs
  for (const i in data) {
    console.log("Opening", data[i]);
    await page.goto(data[i]);
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, I've got how to loop through a selection using `let btns = await page.$$(".btns"); for(const idx in btns){await btns[idx].click(); }`, but this doesn't seem to work if the selections are inside an SVG element, as referenced in my question.

Comment: Ah I see, you have a SVG of buttons not hrefs

Comment: ya its an svg with rects appended into it that I would like to click on. Gotta wait for the issue to be resolved and go from there I think. Should I close this question as its a know issue?

Comment: possibly but up to you